# What is the efficient and concise way to construct a String from Character Stack

Tags: java, java-8, stack

Suppose I have a stack -

```
O (stack top)
L
L
E
H (stack bottom)
```

What is the concise way to convert it to "HELLO"

Now I am doing this way -

```
private static String getString(Stack<Character> charStack) {
  StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

  while (!charStack.isEmpty()) {
      output.append(charStack.pop());    
  }

  return output.reverse().toString();
}
```

Comment: Define "best", what did you try? By stack do you mean java.util.Stack?

Comment: well, defined, edited. Yes, java.util.Stack

Comment: Appending to a stringbuilder until the stack is empty seems sensible to me

Comment: Note that `Stack` is a very old class that should not be used anymore. It even says in its own documentation to switch to implementations of `Deque` like `ArrayDeque` or `LinkedList`.

Comment: With a stream, https://ideone.com/nzcudX ?

Comment: @RC. Minor correction.. Stack of `Character` not a String in the question.

Comment: @nullpointer my bad

Comment: @RC. and another good point to notice as [pointed by Zazuba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46728067/what-is-the-efficient-and-concise-way-to-construct-a-string-from-character-stack?noredirect=1#comment80402607_46728342) that the order of stack should be reverse of what was pushed.

Comment: Am I write that the stack now has the text **added backwards** (*O, L, L, E, H*) such that **LIFO iteration** (*H, E, L, L, O*) will directly yield the **correct output**? This would mean that the current code of OP creates the wrong text due to the `reverse` statement.

Comment: not exactly, this is a stack top to bottom view

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `map` and `Collectors`, one way of doing what the code in question intend would be:

```
return charStack.stream().map(Object::toString).collect(Collectors.joining());
```

***Edit***: As visible from comments [(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46728067/what-is-the-efficient-and-concise-way-to-construct-a-string-from-character-stack/46728342?noredirect=1#comment80402442_46728254) and [(2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46728067/what-is-the-efficient-and-concise-way-to-construct-a-string-from-character-stack/46728342?noredirect=1#comment80482169_46728342), if emptying the stack is an intentional action, you can update the code to include the behaviour as follows:

```
String output = charStack.stream().map(Object::toString).collect(Collectors.joining());
charStack.clear();
return output;
```

Comment: i am not a java guy, but isn't there a reduce method/function? such to write this as,  `collection.reduce(initial_value, lambda)` ? 

ruby: `collection.reverse.inject(""){|e, i| i+=e}`
js: `collection.reduce((i, e) => i+e)`

Comment: According to the OP’s own code example, `reverse` is not required.

Comment: @Holger Please see the note in the answer for the same.

Comment: @marmeladze: this *is* a reduction, optimized to use a mutable `StringBuilder` instead of creating intermediate string objects. If you go even a step further, `charStack.stream().collect(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::append, StringBuilder::append).toString();` uses even less intermediate objects. Of course, `charStack.stream().reduce("", (a,b)->a+b, (a,b)->a+b)` (or `charStack.stream().reduce("", (a,b)->b+a, (a,b)->b+a)` for reversing) will work too, but are less efficient.

Comment: @Holger Ya, actually the input changes not the code. Have edited to mention and revert to the original answer I made to it. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Calling `charStack.clear()` afterwards might be needed to retain the side effect of popping all elements from the stack (if that property of the original code is important)…

Comment: @Holger Why shall that be required for the shared stub? Calling the stream wouldn't be calling the `pop` from Stack there right or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @nullpointer: the code example of the question does call `pop()` in a loop until the stack is empty. If this side effect of emptying the stack is intended, an invocation of `charStack.clear()` has to be added as the stream operation does not empty the stack. Usually, I wouldn’t expect such a method to alter the incoming collection, so I would leave it out, however, if there is such a behavioral difference between the question’s code and the answer’s solution, it’s worth mentioning it.

Comment: @Holger Updated, just to clarify. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

### Note

I accidentally thought you are searching for a **faster version**. However I decided to leave the discussion here as it could be useful for future readers.

---

### Analysis

You can **not achieve a better** version with the given input, at least when talking about complexity classes. Your `Stack` can only be traversed from last to first item, not in the *correct order* for a `String`.

You can not directly use the knowledge that your final `String` needs to be reversed first.

Let's take a look at your code, let's denote by `n` the size of your stack:

```
private static String getString(Stack<Character> charStack) {
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

    // Yields n iterations
    while (!charStack.isEmpty()) {
        output.append(charStack.pop());    
    }

    // reverse creates n iterations
    // toString creates n iterations
    return output.reverse().toString();
}
```

In total we have `3 * n` iterations yielding `O(n)`.

---

### Size known

If you **know the size** of the stack you could experiment with arrays (`Stack` has no `size` method). The advantage of them is that they can be traversed and edited in any direction at no additional cost. Take a look at the following example:

```
int size = ...
char[] textChars = new char[size];

// Yields n iterations
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    // Reversely set the array
    // Setting is done in constant time
    textChars[size - i - 1] = charStack.pop();
}

// Convert the textChars to String
// without using reverse methods
// Yields n iterations
String text = String.valueOf(textChars);
```

In total we have `2 * n` iterations, also yielding `O(n)`.

So it might indeed be slightly faster, provided you **know the size**. However the difference will not be that big, its `O(n)` too.

---

### Size unknown

If you don't know the size you could exchange `char[]` with `ArrayList<Character>` (`LinkedList` would also work, but could be slower):

```
ArrayList<Character> textChars = new ArrayList<>();

// Yields n iterations
for (char c : charStack) {
    // Set the ArrayList
    // Setting is done in constant time
    textChars.add(charStack.pop());
}

// Unfortunately there is no nice method
// to directly convert ArrayList to String
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

// Reversely iterate the ArrayList, the reverse
// direction comes at no additional cost
// Yields n iterations
for (int i = textChars.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    sb.append(textChars.get(i));
}

// Yields n iterations
String text = sb.toString();
```

Now we have about `3 * n` iterations but with a bigger overhead due to `ArrayList` and `Character`. Without having made experiments I would say that your approach is better than any kind of this, if the size is unknown.

Comment: About the "size unknown" , what is `size` in that snippet ? This doesn't seems possible in that context

Comment: Agreed, but then you have the last solution where you state _"If you don't know the size you could exchange char[] with ArrayList<Character>."_ but still use a `size` variable in the first `for` statement...

Comment: @AxelH Indeed, it's late here, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Note that `charStack.pop()` actually **removes** the elements from the stack - are you sure that it is intended?

You could do it like that without removing elements:

```
private static String getString(Stack<Character> charStack) {
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

    for (Character c : charStack) {
        output.append(c);    
    }

    return output.reverse().toString();
}
```

Comment: Yes, absolutely aware of that.

Comment: @shakhawat In that case your approach is fine. I just wouldn't expect that from reading the function's name, and you didn't explain that this is a wanted side-effect.

Comment: @TobiasWeimer this seems like a clarification that could have been a comment to the question rather than an answer.

Comment: @nullpointer Just from reading the first post, he just wants to convert the stack to a string, he didn't mention that clearing elements is a wanted side-effect. So I just assumed that this is unwanted and posted an alternative implementation for that case, which seems to me the more *concise* way to do it.

Comment: Since the condition for the loop is `!charStack.isEmpty()`, it seems this was already known

Comment: Then he should have explained it so we don't have to guess it from sources.

Comment: While this answer itself is useful, it does not answer the question of OP, it's just a *big comment*.